# How to get input to long command in the end

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep, command

Would it be possible to give the input to a very long command in the end of the command ? Below example would explain my query more clearly.

currently while grepping I have to do like below:

```
zgrep -i "A VERY LONG TEXT" file |awk '{print $1}'
```

Every time I have to move the cursor back to the "A VERY LONG TEXT" to change the pattern.I wanted to alter the command in such a way that "A VERY LONG TEXT" comes in the end of the command so I can quickly change it.

```
command1 |command2 |some_magic "A VERY LONG TEXT"
```

I know I can achieve this result by doing CAT and then grepping ,wondering if there is any alternate way to do this. May be like assigning it to a temp variable?

## EXAMPLE 2:

I need to get real time time stamp of all the commands and their output in my session files.So I have to use below command.  But before executing any command I have to move my cursor till unbuffer and change the commands.  Is there is any way I can alter the below command such that I can enter my commands in the end of the line ?

```
    /yumm 194>unbuffer ls -lrt | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'  
    2014-10-01 10:38:19 total 0
    2014-10-01 10:38:19 -rw-rw-r--  1 user bcam 0 Oct  1 10:37 1
    2014-10-01 10:38:19 -rw-rw-r--  1 user bcam 0 Oct  1 10:38 test1
    2014-10-01 10:38:19 -rw-rw-r--  1 user bcam 0 Oct  1 10:38 test2
    2014-10-01 10:38:19 -rw-rw-r--  1 user bcam 0 Oct  1 10:38 test3
    2014-10-01 10:38:19 -rw-rw-r--  1 user bcam 0 Oct  1 10:38 test4
   yumm 195>
```

In short, I need some command to get time stamp of all the commands and their output I execute.

Comment: What part exactly are you going to change? Just `unbuffer` or more things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just set this text to a variable?

```
mystring="A VERY LONG TEXT"
zgrep -i "$mystring" file | awk '{print $1}'
         ^         ^
         note you need double quotes to make it work
```

Based on your edit, you can also do:

```
awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' <<< "$(unbuffer ls -ltr)"
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please see Example 2 ,I have tried to clearly put my query.Sorry for not clearly mentioning my expectations.

Comment: What do you want to change? Just until the pipe? Then, `awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' <<< "$(ls -ltr)"` should make. See my update.

Comment: You understood what I am looking for and I tried your suggestion but Its not working in my server ?
Am I doing something wrong here ?

user>awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' <<< "$(unbuffer ls -ltr)"
Illegal variable name.

Comment: @user2809888 strange, it works fine to me. Are you using normal bash or something different? Also, make sure you copy the answer exactly as it is. Maybe you can also try with just `awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }' <<< "$(ls -ltr)"`. That is, without `ls -ltr`.

Comment: I am using 2.6.14-pne #1  i686 GNU/Linux, I tried using only awk but it only give time stamp for the command. Not getting output of the commands.

Comment: Wondering if xargs could help some how ?

Comment: @user2809888 not sure what to say, I have lost track of what is wrong here. I gave two possible answers that work locally to me, I am not sure why they don't in your system. `xargs` wouldn't be a good way to go, it would overcomplicate. I would go for using a variable, as I initially said.

Answer (score 0):

When editing and re-submitting a command, use:

`Ctrl-A` to move the cursor back to the start of the line quickly

`Ctrl-E` to move to the end of the line quickly

`Alt-F` to move forwards one word

`Alt-B` to move backwards one word

Or use `fc` command to open the last command in the editor and allow you to edit - say with `vi` commands, and then when you save it, it gets re-submitted for execution.

Answer (score 0):

These shortcut key maybe help you.

```
Ctrl-a: move to beginning of line
Ctrl-e: move to end of line
Ctrl-b: move to previous character    
Ctrl-f: move to next character

Ctrl-p: previous command (same as "UP" key in bash history)
Ctrl-n: next command (same as "DOWN" key in bash history)

Ctrl-h: Delete backward character
Ctrl-d: Delete current cursored character
Ctrl-k: Delete characters after cursor
```

You can easily image if you know Emacs editor.
These shortcut is same key bind as same as emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function, e.g., in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
some_magic() {
    zgrep "$1" file | awk '{print $1}'
}
```

And use it the following way:

```
some_magic "A VERY LONG TEXT"
```

As for your second example, as soon as a command output is piped, it gets buffered by the pipe. Therefore the timestamp acquired at the other side of the pipe is wrong. Anyway, if you don't mind having a wrong timestamp, you can use this function:

```
some_other_magic() {
    $1 | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0}'
}
```

And use it the following way:

```
some_other_magic "ls -lrt"
```